# How to add suffix @gmail.com to a list of names

Tags: list, coldfusion

I have a list of names:

```
<cfset myList = "John,Joe,Pete">
```

I want to convert this to a final list that has the string @gmail.com at the end of each name:

```
<cfoutput> #myList# </cfoutput>
```

So it will render as:

```
John@gmail.com,Joe@gmail.com,Pete@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 8):

All you have to do is simple concatenation in a loop.

```
<cfset myList = "John,Joe,Pete" />
<cfloop index="item" list="#myList#">
    <cfoutput>#item#@gmail.com<br /></cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: You need octothorps around the list attribute in your cfloop tag.

Comment: Its ok Sterling, Dan's been wanting to use "octothorp" in a sentence all week! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a comma separated list having no spaces in between you can use this also:

```
<cfset mylist1 = rereplace(mylist, "," , "@gmail.com," , "all") & "@gmail.com" />
```

Not the best solution but may be helpful in specific cases.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you very much...Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<cfset myList = "John,Joe,Pete">
<cfset newList = reReplace(myList, "(?=,|$)", "@gmail.com", "ALL")>
```